# Disconnection issues

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom, disconnect

As I'm using WiFi, the computer I use, sometimes disconnects, as my router switches off periodically. But when its back on, Ubuntu won't connect to it, and will ask me the Router WPA key.

Is there any way to configure Ubuntu such that it doesn't ask me a password after some time of disconnection and repeatedly try to obtain connection until it has done so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing this program:

```
sudo aptitude install wifi-radar
```

and setting up a profile for your wifi this program will automatically try to connect to your network no matter what (yes it does connect on startup).

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: Can you give me some information for how to use it for connecting with a static ip?